# Does MongoDb XSD for Spring Data - Document define a db-factory element?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-document

Spring Data - Document [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/) gives and [example](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e1202) of configuring a factory bean for creating MongoDB connections using `mongo:db-factory` element.

```
<mongo:db-factory id="anotherMongoDbFactory"
              host="localhost"
              port="27017"
              dbname="database"
              username="joe"
              password="secret"/>
```

The problem is that the [XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd) for the mongo namespace does not declare a db-factory element. Is this a bug or am I looking at incorrect version of documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **mongo:db-factory** element is available from **Spring-Data 1.0 Milestone 3**. The package can be downloaded from [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/milestone/SDMONGO/spring-data-document-1.0.0.M3.zip) and the documentation can be found at [Spring-Data 1.0.0.M3 Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html).

To use it from Maven, just include the following dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
</dependency>
```

Probably you were using the 1.0.0.M2 version of the code ([Spring-Data 1.0.0.M2 Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html)) where the db-factory was not yet available in the XSD or the online documentation.